# Why does clock() function in C from <time.h> header only returns clock ticks in increments of 10's of thousands?

Tags: c, performance, libraries, real-time, time

I am curious to know why does the function clock() only returns values in increments of 10,000 and is not able to return values in between.

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    clock_t clock_start;
    time_t start1;
    time(&start1);
    clock_start = clock();

    for(int i=0;i<200000;i++)
        cout<<8;

    time_t end1;
    time(&end1);

    clock_t clock_end = clock();

    int b;
    printf("\n\n%d",end1-start1);
    printf("\nClock ticks ?? = %d",clock_end-clock_start);
    return 0;
}
```

The result is either 0 or 10,000

There is no in-between.

The same situation is happening even if I modify the number of iterations the 'for' loop runs. The values are also multiple of 10,000

What is the reason behind this behavior and what is a practical use case for the "clock" function in this case? It seems quite unreliable to me.

Comment: Just like thread scheduling, this kind of clock function only gets incremented every couple of milliseconds (on windows it varies between 0.5 and 16ms, depending on applications having requested shorter ticks). If you want precision timing, use  high precision functions, like Windows's `QueryPerformanceCounter`.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It is actually incremented every second which I find actually ridiculous.... I am running Linux on x86

Comment: Try `clock_gettime()` instead.  https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime.

Comment: See also [C Tutorial: Use Linux's high resolution clock](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/gettime.html)

Comment: See also [this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6749621/102937)   The OP has code nearly identical to yours.

Comment: @JenniferAnderson 10'000 clocks is 10ms

Comment: Unfortunately, the accuracy and precision of the function is limited by hardware and software.

Comment: FYI, clock() doesn't report wall-clock time, it reports CPU time, and you're also not using the CLOCKS_PER_SEC constant.

Comment: With multiple cores, it is likely that CPU time will run considerably faster than actual elapsed time.

Comment: @whatsisname Then how can I precision time real time in C?

Comment: @user16217248L use your OS provided functions to access the hardware's high-precision timers. But remember, there again you can only measure elapsed time, not wall-clock time. Wall clock time you can't do any better than a few milliseconds precision.